# Laravel queue push listener - queue monitoring

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-queue

I am using the `JobProcessing`, `JobProcessed` and `JobFailed` to populate a queue logs table.

I would like to also listen for an event as jobs are pushed to the queue. Does this exist?

I see from running:

```
\Redis::lrange('queues:mws', 0, -1)
```

That a pushedAt parameter exists, but I am unsure how to get this in an event prior to the job actually being processed.

This is fundamentally in order to check that my queues are all:

- a) actually running (the workers have not stopped).
- b) the job processing time is not too long.

Comment: *I would like to also listen for an event as queues are pushed to the queue* - confused by this. Did you mean you want to dispatch an event when a job is queued?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my typo. I meant "listen for an event when jobs are pushed to the queue`. I was hoping laravel may dispatch an event every time a job is pushed (as it does when a job is processing, processed or failed). If laravel does not do this by default, is it possible for me to define this globally for all job dispatches? I know how to do this within each job class, but I would like to ensure its enabled by default for every push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, you can get this information when using horizon by listening for the `JobPushed` event. The payload for this event contains the job ID, name, connetion and queue etc.

```
Event::listen(JobPushed::class, function(JobPushed $event){
    \Log::debug('JobPushed Event Fired ', [
        'connection' => $event->connectionName,
        'queue' => $event->queue,
        'payload' => [
            'id' => $event->payload->id(),
            'displayName' => $event->payload->displayName(),
            'commandName' => $event->payload->commandName(),
            'isRetry' => $event->payload->isRetry(),
            'retryOf' => $event->payload->retryOf(),
        ]
    ]);
});
```