# Laravel job pushed to queue event

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-6

In Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues#job-events) there is `Queue::before` and `Queue::after` events. What I'm looking for is "job pushed to queue" or "job created" event, something like `Queue::pushed`. Is that exists or how can I trigger that event?

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54640510/910548) I saw `JobPushed` event but it's from Laravel Horizon. Is there a way without Horizon?

```php
Queue::before(function (JobProcessing $event) {
    // $event->connectionName
    // $event->job
    // $event->job->payload()
});

Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event) {
    // $event->connectionName
    // $event->job
    // $event->job->payload()
});
```

Comment: you could use pusher for broadcasting the updated status of the queue. let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 2):

you can use your job class cunstructor function as a `job created` event. a job object constructor is executed when you create a new instance of it. but other functions (for example: handle() and ...) would execute when job is running in queue.

also for something near `job pushed to queue` you can override the dispatch function of you job class. job objects have an static function dispatch that pushes a new job object into queue.

so your edited job class would be like these:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SampleJob implements ShouldQueue
{
  use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
  /**
   * Create a new job instance.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->created();
    // rest of code
  }

  /**
   * Execute the job.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function handle()
  {
  }

  public static function dispatch($job)
  {
    SampleJob::dispatch($job);
    $job->pushedToQueue();
  }

  // events 

  public function created()
  {
    // event codes
  }
  public function pushedToQueue()
  {
    // event codes
  }
}
```